# Template ref is undefined in child component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I'm trying to give a template ref to a child component:

```
<div v-for="(item, idx) in  items">
    <div>
      <div>
        <a href="JavaScript:void(0);" title="test" ref="templateRefArray" @click="foobar">
          <div>
            <iconComponent icon="ellipsis-vertical" />
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>


      <p>TEST {{ templateRefArray?.length }} {{ templateRefArray[idx] }}</p>
      <template v-if="templateRefArray[idx]">
        <childComponent v-model:someModelStuff="someModelStuff" :wrapperElement="templateRefArray[idx]" @select="foobar2">
        </childComponent>
      </template>
    </div>
</div>


<script setup>
...
const templateRefArray = ref([]);
</script>
```

The tempalte ref is inside a `v-for` loop. logging the content of `templateRefArray` it shows the referred dom element. So it seems to work. But displaying it on the template or even passing it to a child component doesn't work. The element displays "undefined" as a type and seems to be empty.

Comment: Could be XY problem. Consider explaining your case instead of addressing potentially wrong solution. Template refs may have problems with reactivity. And templateRefArray won't be an array, probably should be `:ref="el => templateRefArray[index] = el"`

Comment: There shouldn't be a problem with reactivity and template refs. Even the docs state this v-for case.

Comment: Your question proves the opposite, so the details are important. This is specific to vue version, the way refs work has been changed in 3.x updates

Comment: Okay, using `3.4.15` fixed it. Guess it really was an "older" Vue's version bug.

Answer (score 0):

Using 3.4.15 fixed this. Seems to be an bug occuring on "older" versions of Vue.